# Connected sum in Alexandrov spaces

Tags: alexandrov-geometry

Is it possible to take connected sums of Alexandrov spaces? More explicitly, can one put a metric that turns the connected sum into an Alexandrov space?  Does it matter if the curvature bound is from above or below?

If it is possible, how exactly does one go about the construction?

Comment: How do you define a connected sum of non-manifolds?


Comment: For general CBB-space, there is no known construction which keep an open set unchanged and change something outside. So your question seems hopeless...

Comment: If I recall correctly for Alexandrov spaces with curvature bounded from below, there is an open dense set which is a manifold, so maybe for this class the construction is possible? 

My intuition tells me that if we take out an open ball contained in this dense manifold maybe we could keep the curvature bounded (although I think with a different bound).

Comment: @Zimbrón, yes it should be this way (in CBB case), 
but there is no machinery is available.